# How to find out if I have reached Object in a chain of super.equals calls?

Tags: java, equals, superclass

I have a problem with Class.getSuperclass(). I want to generate a hierarchy of classes where each child, after comparing its attributes to the other class, passes on the equals request to the parent. With this approach I need to stop calling super.equals when I have reached the level above Object since Object does an isSame comparison and that is not what I want.

Suppose I have this hierarchy:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    ...
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        ... compare my attributes to other, if everything matches:
        if (myImmediateSuperIsObject()) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return super.equals(other)
        }
    }
}



class Parent extends Object {
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        ... compare my attributes to other, if everything matches:
        if (myImmediateSuperIsObject()) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return super.equals(other)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the myImmediateSuperIsObject pseudo call. How to write it?
When Parent.equals is called from Child.equals,  then within Parent, this.getClass().getSuperclass() is not Object, but Parent. That is because when calling getSuperclass(), we are always starting at the class of the instance, which is Child. So I can build the entire hierarchy by recursively calling getSuperclass until I get null, but how do I determine if I'm just above Object in my chain of equals calls?

To reiterate, all this is only an issue because I need to generate the class hierarchy. If I were to write this manually, I would of course know that I am extending object and stop calling super.equals().

Any idea?

Best regards,
Dietrich

Comment: What about introducing one abstract class between `Object` and `Parent` which you define as the root of your hierarchy trees? In that class, you could override `equals` to not do anything anymore.

Comment: The Parent class extends Object. It doesn't have to test if its superclass is Object. It is, and that can't change. So just let the child call `super.equals()`.

Comment: "Object does an isSame comparison and that is not what I want." Can you provide an example where doing this would make any difference or is this just an academic question?

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet . Parent is subclass of Object so there is no need to check that in equals().

Comment: @JB Nizet,  Adam Dyga: This code is generated,  therefore the check in all children although it would not be necessary in manually written code.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I have child1 and child2 both having the exact same attributes, and the semantics of my class hierarchy is that they are to be considered equal.  Object.equals however would say that child1 does not equal child2 because they are not the same instance.

Comment: Object.equals will *only* be true if you are the same instance.  You can't have the same instance but have two classes.

Comment: `if (myImmediateSuperIsObject()) {
           return true;
` As all instances of `Parent` have `Object` as a super, all instances of Parent are equal to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're comparing properties in your object hierarchy, have you considered using [EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)?

Comment: Excellent workaround!  But is it not possible in a call hierarchy to find out what exact type _super_ is in the current call level?

Comment: You don't need to stop it before Object though: the Object properties won't be compared.

Comment: If everything matches, and Object.equals is called, it will compare the instances,  which are usually not the same, so equals will be false although all properties match. Does that better express what I mean?

Comment: reflectionEquals would be pretty useless if it only worked for the same instance.  It compares the fields: it doesn't use equals.

Comment: It seems it is indeed not possible to find out in which level of the inheritance I am while walking up the super hierarchy. Your workaround is therefore the most helpful answer. BTW In the end I was able to adjust the generator - in the UML model it is possible to find out if I am top level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getClass().getSuperClass() and then test if its Object.class

Example:

```
class Animal {
    boolean myImmediateSuperIsObject() {
        System.out.println("I am " + getClass() + " and my parent is " + getClass().getSuperclass());

        return this.getClass().getSuperclass() == Object.class;
    }
}
class Horse extends Animal {
    boolean myImmediateSuperIsObject() {
        System.out.println("I am " + getClass() + " and my parent is " + getClass().getSuperclass());

        return this.getClass().getSuperclass() == Object.class;
    }
}
new Horse().myImmediateSuperIsObject();
new Animal().myImmediateSuperIsObject();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately it does not work when equals is called from child and I am in parent.  I edited the question to make that more clear.